# what is screen reader in bootstrap ducumentation??? >>>[bootstrap document]

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, screen-readers

what is screen reader in bootstrap ducumentation??? >>>[bootstrap document](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-center)

I don't know what is screen reader?

Comment: Is Google not working for you?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_reader

Comment: you mean (screen readers) means blind people??

Comment: In many cases, sure.  But certainly not in all cases.  For example, in the linked article it also mentions the illiterate.  (Such as people who can't read or understand the linked article.)

Comment: To cite the summary of the `screen-readers` tag you added to your question and which you see when you hover your mouse over it: "A screen reader is a piece of software that allows people who are blind or have significant vision loss to use a computer."

Answer (score 6):

It's a tool used by people who can't see well or for some reason can't read from a screen; it reads the text out loud to them, or presents it to them in a different format that they can use more easily.

Answer (score 2):

**What is a Screen Reader?**

A screen reader is a software application that enables people with severe visual impairments to use a computer. Screen readers work closely with the computer’s Operating System (OS) to provide information about icons, menus, dialogue boxes, files and folders. A screen reader provides access to the entire OS that it works with, including many common applications.

Refrence: http://www.nomensa.com/blog/2005/what-is-a-screen-reader